# Pip Install Proxy Settings

Tags: python, git, pip

Since but `PyPI` is out of date; therefore I run the command `pip install --proxy http://XXXXXXXX:80 git+https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git` with proxy(required) in the working dev environment, then I get a connection refused error as follows.

How should I add this package to the project?

[image]

By the way, I could able to download the repository via github website.

Comment: PyCrypto at PyPI is old but I don't see the code in the Github repository is any newer.

Comment: @phd based on the following https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/110

Comment: The pull request mentioned in the issue is not accepted. setup.py dated Jun 23, 2014, just a few days more fresh than PyPI. :-(